# Extract SubString from the File Name SSIS Expression

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have a criteria where I need to extract Year from the File Name

The File name will be in following way

```
FILE.TEST.ASSGN_2012_Retro_Year   Result should be 2012
FILE.TEST.ASSGN_2013_Retro_Year   Result should be 2013
FILE.TEST.ASSGN_2014_Retro_Year   Result should be 2014
```

I am extracting the file name to the Variable called as FileName

I tried below expression in derived column but no luck:

```
SUBSTRING(@[User::FileName], FINDSTRING(@[User::RealFileName], "HASSN_",1,4))
```

Answer (score 4):

You have several typos and improper usage in your current expression.

Try the following Expression. It works.

`SUBSTRING( @[User::RealFileName],FINDSTRING(@[User::RealFileName], "ASSGN_",1)+6,4)`

In my test, I created a variable called `RealFileName` and assigned it your 1st test value of `FILE.TEST.ASSGN_2012_Retro_Year`. 
Then I created a variable called `FileName` and assigned it the expression

`SUBSTRING( @[User::RealFileName],FINDSTRING(@[User::RealFileName], "ASSGN_",1)+6,4)`

See what the **Evaluated value** expression shows for this test value.

[image]